# What's the difference between a django package and a python library?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I've been browsing around the djangopackages site. I'm wondering what is the difference between those "django" packages, and python libraries that are not django packages.

So for example sendgrid has a django package and also a few regular python libraries. If I want to use the sendgrid wrapper from a django app, what benefits do i get by using the django package rather than the other python libraries that are available and more frequently maintained?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Django package has the general structure of a Django app (`models.py`, `views.py`, et cetera) and it can have additional settings to define in your `settings.py` file. Using the Django package makes it easier to integrate the functionality into your Django web application rather than simply calling a Python library.

Usually the Python library provides all the functionality and a Django package provides additional functionality to use it (such as useful template tags, settings or context processors). You'll need to install both as the Django package won't work without the library. But this can vary so you'll need to look into the provided functionalities by the Django package.

Comment: Thanks Simeon, can you make it more clear through an example maybe the benefits of having the package follow the structure of an app with configurable settings?

Comment: What do you mean with benefits? A Django package has to follow the structure of each Django app - it's just the way it works. And within that structure (such as in a directory `templatetags`) additional functionality can be added to make it easier to use the functionality from the Python library.

Comment: Hi! What means **"have additional settings to define in your settings.py"** ? Do you refer "your settings.py" as package/app settings.py or project's settings.py? @SimeonVisser

Answer (score 0):

you need **django** app when you want **django** help you with something in your app so django needs to know about your app (the process of registering your app):

- you have models and you want django to in charge of migrations and stuff
- you have user model define in models and want to use

```
# settings.py -> auth section
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_app.User"
```

in your settings.py (and no, this is not the same check *stateless model of simple jwt*

- you want django to pick up template from you templates folder of your app

```
# settings.py -> template section 
"APP_DIRS": True,
```

you see django need to know what is app to use it

- you want custom template tags django looks for folder name templatetags in again so called **apps**
- you want to write custom commands django looks for folder name management/commands in django apps and guess what ...
  ....
  so if django want to look something in app it have to be app and it have to register in settings.py if not python packages are enough